# How to specify trigger execution order under PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I'm using "classic" time-based partitioning using triggers. I have found a need for a separate trigger, which runs on the original table.

```
CREATE TABLE twitter_interactions(...);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_twitter_interactions ...;
CREATE TRIGGER insert_twitter_interactions_trig
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE on twitter_interactions
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_twitter_interactions();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION maintain_data_pointers ...;
CREATE TRIGGER maintain_data_pointers_trig
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE on twitter_interactions
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_twitter_interactions();
```

I haven't fully verified, but I suspect the partitioning logic runs before the maintain trigger, and since the row doesn't end up in the parent table, then the 2nd trigger never fires.

What happens if I want to run an `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE` as well? Since the row doesn't make it into the original table, then I'm at a loss to implement the after logic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I couldn't say it better than [the manual does here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html):

> If any `BEFORE` or `INSTEAD OF` trigger returns `NULL`, the operation is
> abandoned for that row and subsequent triggers are not fired (for that row).

Neither the (alphabetically) later triggers on the same event nor any `AFTER` triggers will fire, if the `BEFORE` trigger cancels.

Comment: Good old RTFM... But reading the statement, if the insert trigger is *last*, then other triggers can fire and complete. I'll investigate this further. Thanks!

Comment: @FrançoisBeausoleil: That's right. You can squeeze in other triggers on the same event *before* you cancel the INSERT with `RETURN NULL`. You could also put more program code into the same trigger function.

Answer (score 14):

PostgreSQL executes the triggers in alphabetical order by name. So make sure to use names that get them in the order you want. From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html)

> SQL specifies that multiple triggers should be fired in time-of-creation order. PostgreSQL uses name order, which was judged to be more convenient.

BTW your SQL creates the same trigger twice.

Comment: Simple copy paste error. Wrote the SQL above for illustrative purposes. Thanks for the answer!